# flex shrink not working vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

You can see the full code here:https://codepen.io/typhoon93/pen/zabzyz/

I have created a flex container with class: **contact-details-links**

The links inside it are with class "profile-link" and they have set height and width, and flex shrink property explicitly set to: 1; Below is the full code:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact-details-links{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:300px;
    }
.profile-link{
    border: 1px black solid;
    height:200px;
    width: 300px;
    flex-shrink:1;
}
```

When you start to decrease the widht of the page so the "profile-link" boxes begin to overflow, they are not shrinking. I've searched for the last hour but couldn't find anything that can help me here.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

If I remove the height property the items shrink fine, so my guess is there's something I don't know about vertically shrinking these items.

Comment: you are confusing the axis ... flex-shrink work horizontally here since it's a row direction .. height won't shrink since it's fixed and has nothing to do with flex-shrink

Comment: Also if you remove the fixed height you will rely on the stretch property so it's stretching and not shrinking

Comment: Hi Temani, thank you for your answer, this makes sense. However, does that mean that there is no way of actually shrinking in both directions at the same time?

Comment: align-items: flex-start; on .contact-details-links ? I am not sure if I understand where you want to go...

Comment: I would say 'no' as the shrink feature affect only one direction but if you think differently without the shrink it can be a "yes" if you manage your height or you rely on other feature ... like for example the stretch feature if your remove the height, In this situation you have *shrink* on both direction even it's not a realy shrink vertically

Comment: Thanks Temani, this was kinda driving me nuts but now that I know what I want is not possible with inherent features I'll just go around it! Also awesome portfolio site, you kinda inspired me to keep going with this sh.t :)

Comment: you can try `Vertical-align: center`

Answer (score 1):

Temani answered my question in his comment, basically what I want is not really possible with just flex shrink property - it only works in the direction of the main axis - i.e. since my flex is set with direction: row, it only shrinks my item horizontally.

The question is answered, I will do what I want to do with additional code(media queries) or maybe change my desired outcome.

Thanks to everyone for their answers.